# How to Restore a Cloned Drive to Original Size?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, clone

A while back I had a laptop that crashed on me and I was able to successfully clone the hard drive onto a 3 TB WD drive that I had in an enclosure. However I didn't realize at the time, since I had never cloned a drive before, that the 3 TB drive is now a 500 GB drive.

I would like to restore it back to the original 3 TB and I have looked around and the only thing I have really done is check in Disk Management which shows it as a 500 GB drive and I cannot extend the volume. I didn't want to try too many things and possibly damage the drive.

To clone the drive I used ddrescue and SystemRescueCD

If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You could use the SystemRescueCD as it'll most probably have GParted on it - this will let you resize an NTFS partition to use the rest of the disk...

Comment: It should be as simple as using Disk Management to expand the size of the partition.  Have you tried that?  However, I would guess your using MBR, which means the most you will be able to expand it to is 2 TB.

Comment: I have tried going into Disk Management and the option to extend the volume isn't available. It's not showing any additional space, only the 500 GB